# Convert JSON message to javax.jms.ObjectMessage in ActiveMq

Tags: java, node.js, activemq-classic

I have an ActimeMQ consumer which expects a message in javax.jms.ObjectMessage format. 
This message pojo has 5 string elements.

Now I am trying to write a message producer for this consumer in NodeJs. 
I am using [stompit](https://github.com/gdaws/node-stomp) module

My current NodeJs code is

```
stompit.connect(connectOptions, function(error, client) {

if (error) {
    console.log('connect error ' + error.message);
    return;
} else {
    console.log("connected");
}

var sendHeaders = {
    'destination': '/queue/test',

    'transformation': 'jms-object-json'
};
var msg = new Object();
msg.val1 = "12";
msg.val2 = "test";
msg.val3 = "1";
msg.val4 = "1";
msg.val5 = "Y";
var frame = client.send(sendHeaders);
frame.write(JSON.stringify(msg));
frame.end();
```

});
 Java consumer is able to get the message but throws the exception

> org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQTextMessage cannot be cast to javax.jms.ObjectMessage

I have read this [page](http://activemq.apache.org/stomp.html) from activeMQ which says that

> Currently, ActiveMQ comes with a transformer that can transform XML/JSON text to Java objects, but you can add your own transformers as well

I didn't quite understand this part on how to convert data.

I have added xstream-1.4.10.jar and jettison-1.3.8.jar in apache-activemq-5.15.0\lib and restarted the ActiveMq server. 
But still I get the error in the consumer. 
Also in the ActiveMQ console -> Queues -> message properties, it shows transformation-error

Please let me know how I can convert this ActiveMQTextMessage type to javax.jms.ObjectMessage before it reaches the consumer

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a transformer in ActiveMQ that will convert any random JSON string into and ObjectMessages, you'd have to write you own to handle whatever format you are sending.  The converter in ActiveMQ will convert some basic types that Map from the JSON but it's tricky and not necessarily reliable.  You are better off handling the TextMessage and doing something meaningful with the JSON yourself.

Comment: What does this transformation  'jms-object-json' do then? And what does that statement "ActiveMQ comes with a transformer that can transform XML/JSON text to Java objects" in activemq website mean?

Answer (score 0):

ActiveMQTextMessage and ObjectMessage  are different , they can't cast to each other.

From ActiveMQTextMessage , you can get the true message content as a String, then you have to trans it to a json object yourself.